# When does a transaction expire?

Tags: transaction, blockhash

The docs contradict themselves on this in a number of places. Which of the following most accurately describes when a transaction expires?

**a)** after 150 blocks have been appended to the chain after the block identified by the transaction's recent blockhash

**b)** after 300 blocks have been appended to the chain after the block identified by the transaction’s recent blockhash

**c)** after 151 slots have elapsed since the slot during which the block identified by the transaction’s recent blockhash was produced

**d)** none of the above

These docs imply that the answer is **(a)**:

1. https://docs.solana.com/integrations/retrying-transactions#how-rpc-nodes-broadcast-transactions:~:text=the%20transaction%E2%80%99s%20blockhash%20expires%20(150%20blocks
2. [https://docs.solana.com/terminology#skipped-slot:~:text=nor%20increment%20the%20block%20height%2C%20nor%20expire%20the%20oldest%20recent_blockhash](https://docs.solana.com/terminology#skipped-slot:%7E:text=nor%20increment%20the%20block%20height%2C%20nor%20expire%20the%20oldest%20recent_blockhash) (this seems to imply that blocks rather than slots determine transaction expiry)

However, on mainnet, when I attempt to submit a transaction with a recent blockhash of a block produced more than 150 blocks before the latest confirmed block height reported by `getBlockHeight`, the transaction is never included in a block. This is true even if `isBlockhashValid` reports that the blockhash is still valid.

These imply that the answer is **(b)**:

1. api.mainnet-beta.solana.com’s getLatestBlockhash and isBlockhashValid implementations
2. https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getlatestblockhash
3. https://docs.solana.com/api/http#isblockhashvalid

This doc implies that the answer is **(c)**:

1. https://docs.solana.com/developing/transaction_confirmation#how-does-transaction-expiration-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me preface this with: I'm also not 100% sure on this

but here is my guess: the answer is a)

**A transaction expires when the recent blockhash included in the transaction cannot be found within the 150 most recent blockhashes.** With the exception of transactions using durable-nonces.

This is my intuitive answer as the recent blockhashes sysvar also has exactly 150 hashes:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/SysvarRecentB1ockHashes11111111111111111111/blockhashes

And I also came to that conclusion when stepping through the source code
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/accounts-db/src/blockhash_queue.rs#L61

I don't think it's 300 (I also don't see it in the docs you linked)
and I also don't think it's 151 slots. That's probably a off by 1 error and each slot has a block assumption. But again, I might be wrong.

Comment: This is the correct answer!